# SQL Server: Rewrite recursive CTE to substitute for option maxrecursion in a View

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

I ran into the issue that we cannot use underneath query inside a view, but only in a table. Unfortunately we deal with the situation that we don't have tables as an option for this project.

I am curious whether someone knows in what direction I should look for to substitute for underneath logic:

What I try to do is create a record for each day within a date range, by doing the following query:

```
WITH CTE_PerDay AS (
    SELECT 
         TableDateRange.objectId
        ,TableDateRange.amount
        ,TableDateRange.beginDate
        ,COALESCE(TableDateRange.endDate, '2099-12-31') AS endDate
    FROM TableDateRange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         CTE_PerDay.objectId
        ,CTE_PerDay.amount
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, CTE_PerDay.beginDate) AS beginDate
        ,CTE_PerDay.endDate
    FROM CTE_PerDay 
    WHERE GETDATE() > DATEADD(DAY, 1, CTE_PerDay.beginDate)

)
SELECT * FROM CTE_PerDay
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Sample Dataset `TableDataRange`

| ObjectId | Amount | beginDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2020-01-03 |  |
| 2 | 35 | 2015-05-31 | 2019-10-01 |
| 3 | 200 | 2017-03-15 | 2020-06-02 |

```
CREATE TABLE TableDateRange
(
     ObjectId   varchar(300),
     Amount     int,
     beginDate  date,
     endDate    date
);

INSERT INTO TableDateRange ( ObjectId , Amount , beginDate , endDate )
VALUES
    ('1', 500, '2020-01-03', NULL),
    ('2', 35, '2015-05-31', '2019-10-01'),
    ('3', 200, '2017-03-15', '2020-06-02');
```

So the query runs fine, however in a view I can't use the `OPTION` functionality, and without it I get the error 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.'
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a tally: that's a set-based solution, that performs better than recursion when the number of iterations increases - and it is supported in views.

Here is an approach:

```
select t.objectid, t.amount, dateadd(day, x.n, t.begindate) as dt
from (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1
    from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
) x(n)
inner join tabledatarange t
    on dateadd(day, x.n, t.begindate) <= case 
        when enddate <= convert(date, getdate()) then enddate
        else convert(date, getdate())
    end
```

The tally generates all numbers between 0 and 999 (you can easily expand it by adding `cross join`s). We use it to "multiply" the rows of the original table and generate the date range.

I attempted to rewrite the part the handles the end date. I understand that you don't want future dates, so that's what the condition in the `on` clause does.

For this sample data:

```
ObjectId | Amount | beginDate  | endDate   
-------: | -----: | :--------- | :---------
       1 |    500 | 2020-12-28 | null      
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-26 | 2019-10-01
       3 |    200 | 2020-05-28 | 2020-06-02
```

The query returns:

```
objectid | amount | dt        
-------: | -----: | :---------
       1 |    500 | 2020-12-28
       1 |    500 | 2020-12-29
       1 |    500 | 2020-12-30
       1 |    500 | 2020-12-31
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-26
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-27
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-28
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-29
       2 |     35 | 2019-09-30
       2 |     35 | 2019-10-01
       3 |    200 | 2020-05-28
       3 |    200 | 2020-05-29
       3 |    200 | 2020-05-30
       3 |    200 | 2020-05-31
       3 |    200 | 2020-06-01
       3 |    200 | 2020-06-02
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3395560bfbb8766acb64bc72b22b0898)**

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you asked is: Add `OPTION` to the outer query. A view is just a subquery and cannot therefore contain a query level hint.

The question that you didn't ask is: is this actually the best method for a calendar table?

And the answer is: no. Recursing 28854 times in a CTE is very bad for performance.

Much better is either to have a calendar table on disk, or to use Itzik Ben-Gan's [tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) (I would probably do this in a Table Valued Function):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDates
    ( @startDate as DateTime, @endDate as DateTime )
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
(
WITH
  L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
  L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
  L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
  L3 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B ),
  L4 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B ),
  L5 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B ),
  Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
            FROM L5 )

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
    DATEADD(day, rownum, '1999-12-31')
FROM Nums
);
```