# List count for last 12 months broken down by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that can get a total active count of products until a specified date `@POINT`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.productId) CNT
FROM
    pro p
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 p2.*
        FROM
            pro p2
        WHERE
            p2.productId = p.productId
            AND p2.date >= @POINT
            AND p2.STATUS IN ('SOLD', 'ACTIVE')
        ORDER BY
            p2.date ASC
    ) NEXT
WHERE
    p.date < @POINT
    AND p.STATUS = 'SOLD'
    AND NEXT.productId IS NOT NULL
```

Output for `@POINT "01/01/2021"` is

```
CNT
500
```

From a table like

```
productId date       STATUS
1001      01/04/2021 ACTIVE
1002      01/06/2021 SOLD
1003      01/07/2021 OTHER
...
```

How would I remake this query so that I can have a list of points (last 12 months) like

```
POINT       CNT
02/01/2021  550
01/01/2021  500
12/01/2020  450
...
03/01/2020  550
```

in one query? I don't want to create a separate table of dates. The database is MSSQL.

---

Since no responded to question, I'll assume there isn't a function to generate these dates efficiently. I wrote a subquery that CAST couple dates to varchar to date, resulting with first months for the past 12 months.

Comment: I think sample data, desired results, and a *clear* explanation of the logic would be helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My query gets me the results of what I need for any date I specified as shown in my question. Instead of me manually typing in the other various first month dates, I want the query to get me the last 12 first month dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added sample data. Desired results is already in there. I'm not sure how to "clear" up my explanation further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group it by the `Point` and `COUNT(*)` the result.

You say in your update "CAST couple dates to varchar to date", which I think means you want just the date part, in which case you can use `CAST(NEXT.date AS date)`:

```sql
SELECT
    NEXT.date POINT,    -- or CAST(NEXT.date AS date)
    COUNT(*) CNT
FROM
    pro p
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 p2.*
        FROM
            pro p2
        WHERE
            p2.productId = p.productId
            AND p2.date >= @POINT
            AND p2.STATUS IN ('SOLD', 'ACTIVE')
        ORDER BY
            p2.date ASC
    ) NEXT
WHERE
    p.date < @POINT
    AND p.STATUS = 'SOLD'
    AND NEXT.productId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    NEXT.date;    -- or CAST(NEXT.date AS date)
```

Comment: This won't work since I need a query that set @POINT to the first of every month for the past 12 months.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, can you elaborate?

Comment: If I run my original query `@POINT = '01/01/2021'`, it would result with 500. I have to run the past 12 months (ie `@POINT = '12/01/2020', '11/01/2020', ... '1/01/2020'`) . Instead of manually entering the first of the month for the last 12 months, I want to automatically do it. I figured out an inefficient way after I posted my question but hoping for a better feature in MSSQL.

Comment: Still not clear *"result with 500"* 500 of what? So you would like to aggregate by month? There is the `EOMONTH` function, or you can use `DATEFROMPARTS` then you group by that value. Or do you mean to say that you would like to generate a date table on the fly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520461/sql-server-rewrite-recursive-cte-to-substitute-for-option-maxrecursion-in-a-vie/65520565#65520565 And neither of these two was anywhere in your question, you really need to be much clearer about what you want

Comment: 500 is the sample result of my query (found in my question) and in this case, its active products but that's irrelevant. I'm trying to set `@POINT` for each of the last 12 months via SQL rather than manually running my query 12 times with the `@POINT` set manually to each month.

Comment: See my post I just linked for a way to generate dates on the fly. But your current query anyway has issues: 1. Why `OUTER APPLY` if you need `NOT NULL` why not just `CROSS APPLY`? 2. Can you not use window aggregates to get the same result?

Comment: You are right about CROSS APPLY. Not sure why I didn't use it. By window aggregates, do you mean like GROUP BY with COUNT, SUM, etc? How would you use them to get the same result?

Comment: I'm thinking: `LEAD` to get the next row's value, then `LAST_VALUE` partitioned by month, then `GROUP BY month`. A month table would be very useful here. It's somewhat compicated by the fact your `STATUS` filter is not the same in the two queries. But I really couldn't help you with that, because I have no idea what you are trying to do with this query

Comment: I won't be able to use those components but it was still insightful. Thanks!